# One QWebView -> Many QWebPage

Tags: qt, qt4, qtwebkit

How is it possible to handle "Open link in new window" to open a new `QWebPage` instead of new window, saving the previous QWebPage in a stack and show the new one with `QWebView::setPage()`?

I'm new to Qt (and even C++), recommendation on how to fix the stack is also appreciated.

Comment: I don't think QtWebKit (and WebKit in general) supports serializing/deserializing its state into/from a stack.

Maybe it would be helpful if you describe what problems you are trying to solve?

Comment: I was thinking of having one QWebView shared by many QWebPage. Currently, opening a link with "_target=blank" will fork a new QWebView IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

to force opening links in the same `QWebView`, If they are "links"

you can set [linkDelegationPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#linkDelegationPolicy-prop) for the `QWebPage` to `QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks`
and then catch `linkClicked` signal of `QWebPage` and create a new `QWebPage` with the `url` in the argument of the signal

As for the stack, you can do that manually too. Have a `QList` / `QVector` and whenever you get a new `QWebPage` from the above signal, add the current `QWebPage` to the stack and then create the new `QWebPage` and set it as the `QWebView::setPage()`

you can also try subclassing [triggerAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#triggerAction) in `QWebPage` and then check the requested action and if its `QWebPage::OpenLinkInNewWindow` call the base class function and give the action as `QWebPage::OpenLink` instead.

Not sure if this will work in all cases but worth a try if it does for you.